# keeping vector of const reference to the leaf objects of a tree like structure in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a tree like structure in my program like the following:

```
struct A {
    vector<string> m_vStr;
};

struct B {
    vector<A> m_vA;

    // implemented with nested for loops
    const string& getStringWithIndex(size_t i) const; 
};
```

The structure will hardly change but I go through accessing the leafs (I mean the elements of `m_vStr`) too often calling `getStringWithIndex` so I decided to have something like one of the followings:

```
vector<const string*> vstr1;
vector<const string&> vstr2; // Error forming pointer to reference type
vector<reference_wrapper<const string&>> vstr3; // forming pointer to reference type
```

which will be updated whenever the structure is changed and I could use them for more efficient calling of `getStringWithIndex` instead of nested for loops. as you see the last two generates error (why?) and I want to know what choices I have here mostly want to know how to store these const references for easy access. And I could use any new features introduced in C++11 to C++17.

Comment: `vector<reference_wrapper<const string>> vstr3;` is the correct usage - a wrapper for a string, not for a reference to a string, so delete the `&`.

Comment: @KenY-N vector of reference-wrapper is not the same as vector of references

Comment: @Ken Y-N. thanks now I see my problem. Is there any Data structure I could use for this kind of problem. please post with your comment in the answer so that I could mark it correct